# How to implement a generic SingleSelectionView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, swift-protocols

I try to implement a **generic View**, that should render an array of any items, that are *identifiable* in a `ScrollView`. In the view I want to use a view model object that conforms to the protocol `SingleSelectionManager`, that should provide the data (of type `Item`) and do some other things.

**This is my protocol:**

```
protocol SingleSelectionManager : AnyObject {

   associatedtype Item : Identifiable

   var items : Array<Item> { get }

   func isThisSelected(item: Item) -> Bool
   func userDidTapOn(item : Item)
}
```

And this is **my generic View**, that causes a lot of errors:

```
struct GenericSingleSelectionView<Item, Content: View> : View {

let selectionManager : any SingleSelectionManager
var rowContent: (Item, Bool) -> Content

var body: some View {
    LazyVStack {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            ForEach(selectionManager.items) { item in
                rowContent(item, selectionManager.isThisSelected(item: item))
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectionManager.userDidTapOn(item: item)
                    }
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I know, I could use a SwiftUI List, but I prefer this approach.
I always struggled with generic protocols and associated types, but most of the time I found a solution. Not in this case.

Within the ForEach view, there are several errors (maybe because this itself is a generic view), like:

*Cannot convert value of type 'Array' to expected argument type 'Binding'*

*Member 'userDidTapOn' cannot be used on value of type 'any SingleSelectionManager'; consider using a generic constraint instead*

**I would like to know:**

1. Is this even realizable? If so, what I am missing?
2. Is this generally not possible? If so, what are the reasons?

Thanks for **any help.**

Comment: To start with, shouldn't selectionManager be an ObservableObject? Have you tried to first implement this view with a real type to see that it works as expected and then extract a protocol from that type?

Comment: Thanks Joakim, I tried it the non generic way and it works fine. I also tried the selectionManager be an @ObservedObject, but this is not the solution, I think the problem is, that associated type 'Item", it should be more 'contstrained', but I don't know how.

Comment: I have no problem getting a solution that compiles and runs but isn't something supposed to happen in the view when the user tap on an item (and userDidTapOn gets called)? Shouldn't the view update when the selection manager changes?

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is 'any'. It doesn't work with associatedtype fine. If you want to use Observedobject, it won't work. Just use generics, try this one.

Or you can implement 'AnySingleSelectionManager'manually, and it'll work.

```
struct GenericSingleSelectionView<Content: View, Manager: SingleSelectionManager>: View {
   
   let selectionManager : Manager
   var rowContent: (Manager.Item, Bool) -> Content
   
   var body: some View {
      LazyVStack {
         ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            ForEach(selectionManager.items) { item in
               rowContent(item, selectionManager.isThisSelected(item: item))
                  .contentShape(Rectangle())
                  .onTapGesture {
                     selectionManager.userDidTapOn(item: item)
                  }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And it works.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
         GenericSingleSelectionView(
            selectionManager: SingleSelectionManagerImpl(),
            rowContent: { item, flag in
               Text(item.name)
            }
         )
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a nice hint: Using a generic class, in this case 'Manager' instead of a generic protocol.

Comment: Yes, class manager looks good in this case. 
But exactly, I didn't realize, why the container, which created 'any' keyword, doesn't conform 'Identifiable' protocol in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is when using `any SingleSelectionManager`, `selectionManager.items` is different type from item in `rowContent(item`

```
ForEach(selectionManager.items) { item in
    rowContent(item, selectionManager.isThisSelected(item: item))
```

But if you change `any SingleSelectionManager` to a generic class like this

```
let selectionManager : Manager<Item>
```

and Manager being

```
class Manager<Item: Identifiable>: SingleSelectionManager {
    var items: [Item] {
        return []
    }

    func isThisSelected(item: Item) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func userDidTapOn(item: Item) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: This is actually a nice hint: Using a generic class instead of a generic protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with this solution. Thanks to @Christian Moler and @where_am_I for the hint to use a generic *class* instead of a generic *protocol*. Turns out, the protocol isn't necessary at all.

So this is my solution, that works:

```
class SingleSelectionManager<Item : Identifiable> : ObservableObject {
    
    var items: Array<Item>
    @Published var selectedItem : Item?
    
    init(items: Array<Item>, selectedItem: Item? = nil) {
        self.items = items
        self.selectedItem = selectedItem
    }
    
    func isThisSelected(item: Item) -> Bool {
        selectedItem == nil ? false : selectedItem!.id == item.id
    }
    
    func userDidTapOn(item: Item) {
        selectedItem = isThisSelected(item: item) ? nil : item
    }
}

struct GenericSingleSelectionView<Item : Identifiable, Content: View> : View {

    @ObservedObject private (set) var selectionManager : SingleSelectionManager<Item>
    
    var rowContent: (Item, Bool) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(selectionManager.items) { item in
                    rowContent(item, selectionManager.isThisSelected(item: item))
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectionManager.userDidTapOn(item: item)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```